# Latest RabbitMQ release with exchange type x-modulus-hash?

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I understand that the exchange type `x-modulus-hash` has given its place to `x-consistent-hash`. I am trying to deploy an app, the source code for which uses `x-modulus-hash` and I can't change it.

Which version of `RabbitMQ` should I revert back to? I am deploying the app using the [stolon/rabbitmq-ha](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/rabbitmq-ha) helm chart. It would be more useful to know the suitable version for this chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, my bad! `x-modulus-hash` has not been discontinued. It is an exchange type that will be add when the [sharding plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding) is enabled using the following command:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_sharding
```